# How to get a correct automatic row height calculation when modifying the layout inside a UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews() method?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, row-height, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a `UITableView` with cells that are variable in height, laid out with Auto Layout in Interface Builder (`rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`). When the user rotates the device I perform some manual layout changes inside the cell that affect the `intrinsicContentSize` one of the cell's subviews. As these changes are dependent on the initial frame of that particular subview I can only apply these changes once the layout engine has resolved the constraints and applied the correct frames to all subviews for the new (rotated) layout. This happens inside the `layoutSubviews()` method. So to apply my manual changes I override that method and first call the super implementation.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Call `super` implementation to let the layout engine do its job 
    // and apply the new frames to subviews after resolving constraints.
    super.layoutSubviews() 

    //  Apply manual layout changes here
}
```

Now the problem is that my manual layout changes possibly **also change the cell's height**. Hence I need a way to inform the table view that a *second layout pass* is required for this cell before the (automatic) height calculation returns. (Otherwise the table view will just use the row height it computed *before* the manual layout changes.)

Usually you do this by invalidating the layout with a `setNeedsLayout()` call on the view that needs another layout pass. However, I cannot do this from inside the `layoutSubviews()` method because it would result in an infinite loop of layout passes and crash the app.

So I tried to figure out a way if the layout had changed in this particular call of `layoutSubviews()` and came up with this approach:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    // Get old image view size before layout pass
    let previousImageSize = imageView.frame.size

    // Run a layout pass
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // Get the new image view size
    let newImageSize = imageView.frame.size

    // Only trigger a new layout pass if the size changed
    if newImageSize != previousImageSize {

        //  Apply manual layout changes here

        // Trigger another layout pass
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

}
```

*(In this example, the `imageView` is a subview of the cell on which my layout depends.)*

When running this code I realized that the code inside the `if` branch is never executed, i.e. the `imageView` size never changes inside the `layoutSubviews()` method. But it *does* change - only at a different time.

That's inconsistent to my understanding Auto Layout in general:

> A view is always responsible for laying out its subviews, i.e. for setting their frames appropriately and this is done in `layoutSubviews()`.

---

#### So here are my questions:

1. Why does the system change the image view's size from *outside* the `layoutSubviews()` method?

and more importantly:

2. **How can I get the table view to run a second layout pass when computing the row height for a cell?**

Comment: I think you you are looking at it the wrong way. If you want cells with dynamic heights you might want to look into this tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: What is the right way then? My question here is not how to get self-sizing table view cells with Auto Layout in general. The question is how to get properly sized table view cells (or rows) in cases where you need to *modify* the cell's layout and you can't use constraints for that.

Comment: Well based on the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews. You can either use setNeedsLayout() to force a layout update prior to the next drawing update or layoutIfNeeded() to force the update immediately. But I assum you already read this?

Comment: Yes, I guess I'm pretty familiar with the layout process in general. As far as I know when you invalidate the layout during a layout pass (i.e. inside 'layoutSubviews()') by calling 'setNeedsLayout()' another layout pass is triggered which is why I put it in the if branch above to avoid a loop.